# Unit testing / Mocking mongoose models with sinon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

so I have a node module like:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.user)
    .then(user => {
      req.body.user = user._id;
      req.body.company = user.company;
      next();
    }, err => {
      req.send(400, err);
    });
};
```

So, in this case, I want to ensure the proper things are attached to the `req.body`.  So, how would I go about mocking the `User` function?  I have to load the model first so this code doesn't throw an error before calling `mongoose.model` so maybe something to do with actually stubbing the global `require`?  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just discovered `proxyquire` https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire and it was like the heavens opened and shined a light down upon me for the most glorious "ah ha" moment.  No more having to load models in mongoose before trying to use them!

The code to mock mongoose looks something like:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire'),
  expect = require('chai').expect,
  Promise = require('bluebird'),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  USERID = 'abc123',
  COMPANY = 'Bitwise',
  mongooseStub = {
    mongoose: {
      model: (name, schema) => ({
        findById: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({_id: USERID, company: COMPANY});
          });
        }
      })
    }
  },
  attachUser = proxyquire('../lib/users/attach-user', mongooseStub);
```

That will effectively load the `attach-user` module, while stubbing out the `mongoose.model` function to return something I can control.  Then the rest of my test just calls out to the module function and can make assertions as expected.